# Arrays vs Rows in databases

Tags: database, postgresql

I need to store many values in a database. The quantity of values could vary. I am using postgreSQL, and it gives me the possibility of using arrays to store data. My question is:

¿What are the advantages and disadvantages of using arrays or rows to store a dynamic quantity of data?

Comment: What’s your definition of “many” ? A single table can handle billions of rows and using table partitioning you can use at least hundreds of partitions (tables) to create a single massive virtual table

Comment: Hello @FrankHeikens. I do not think the problem is the quantity instead of dynamic size. I was wondering if I could design a database without complex relationships among tables, using arrays instead. Thank you for your response.